# Xcode 8 no longer builds to device

Tags: ios, xcode, beta

I'm currently running Xcode 8.1 beta and have a stable release of Xcode 8 installed as well.
Out of nowhere, without modifying any code inside the project, I am unable to build my project and run on a device.
iOS version is 10.1 beta but the issue was not present when originally working with this version.
 Xcode 8 and 8.1 are experiencing the same issue and I previously did not have a problem running the project on a physical device.
The provisioning profiles were up to date and I created new ones throughout the troubleshooting process.
I have also gone through the basic troubleshooting options (restart the machine, restart the device, cleaned project, tried different lightning cable/USB port, reinstalled Xcode, and deleted Xcode preference files).
The project builds and runs very quickly to the simulator and when attempting to run on the device I received no errors.
When trying to run on a device, the build goes through the first tenth of the process and just sits there until I cancel it.
 I've even created new test projects to test against a known good and the issue persists.
If anyone has experienced, a similar issue your insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you got any solution ? i have same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue but installed latest  Xcode 8.1 and issue got resolved

Answer (score 0):

[image: Correct Command Line Tools]

When you have multiple versions of Xcode installed the command line tools loses track of which Xcode to run. Make sure that this is set. Having multiple versions has always been troublesome for me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue ended up being with a large number of dictionaries. The compiler was attempting to go through a rather large number of dictionaries and was unable to complete. I restructured my data model and the issue was resolved.